# Problema ao alterar textura de um gameobject no Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou a fazer um trabalho no Unity em que o objectivo passa por detectar expressões faciais com o Kinect. No Unity a expressão default é "neutro" e consoante mudamos de expressão para "sorridente" ou "suprendido" a cara que ele mostra deveria mudar.

Eu usei um gameobject ao qual chamei Face e atribuí várias texturas e queria que ele alternasse entre elas quando mudamos a expressão, mas por alguma razão não quer funcionar.

Estou a usar C#. Inicialmente defini:

```
public static Texture[] textures = new Texture[7];
public Texture neutral, smiling, happy, angry, sad, kissing, surprised;
public GameObject Face;
public Renderer rend;
```

No start tenho isto:

```
    player = GameObject.Find ("Face");

    textures[0] = neutral;
    textures[1] = smiling;
    textures[2] = happy;
    textures[3] = angry;
    textures[4] = sad;
    textures[5] = sad;
    textures[6] = surprised;
```

Contudo ele não encontra o "Face", mas eu meti pelo inspector.
No Update depois faço:

```
    ClassifyAndApply(numbers);
```

E isto está definido mais abaixo assim:

```
private void SaveAnimUnits()
    {
        numbers[0] = _animUnits.LipRaiser;
        numbers[1] = _animUnits.JawLowerer;
        numbers[2] = _animUnits.LipStretcher;
        numbers[3] = _animUnits.BrowLowerer;
        numbers[4] = _animUnits.LipCornerDepressor;
        numbers[5] = _animUnits.OuterBrowRaiser;
    }

    private void ClassifyAndApply(float[] units){

//      Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
//      Face = GameObject.Find ("Face");



        if (units[2] <= 0.264888){
            if (units[3] <= 0.817408){
                if (units[1] <= 0.181886){
                    if (units[0] <= -0.216908){
                        if (units[4] <= 0.395523){
                            if (units[1] <= 0.104226){ 
                                Face. GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = textures[3];
                            }
                            else{ 
                                Face. GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = textures[0];
                            }
```

Isto continua, é só um bocado da árvore de decisões.
O problema é que ele não muda a textura quando eu faço as expressões.

Toda a ajuda é bem vinda! Obrigado

Comment: Oi André. Uma pergunta que pode parecer meio óbvia: você separou o código da árvore de decisão com o código da atualização de textura, *apenas para testar*? Em outras palavras, você se certificou de que a linha que faz a alteração de textura está *de fato* sendo executada (isto é, entrou em todos os `if`s do seu código)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado pela ajuda,

Percebi depois que o meu problema era com os units[ ]. Ele não recebia os valores.

Como eu utilizei o Facetracking starter kit da asset store do unity, quando desactivei o game object da cara do diabo, deixei de receber os valores para os Animation Units, que são esses units[ ] neste código.

Quando voltei a activar, já recebi os valores e já funcionou.